# minimizing distance between $A_t$ & $B_t$ , intersections of tangent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

So I have a function

$$f(x)=\frac{a^{n+1}}{x^n} $$

It's derivative is:
$$f'(x)=-n\frac{a^{n+1}}{x^{n+1}} $$

Where $a>0, n \in \mathbb{N}.$
So let $t$ be a tangent to the graph of function $f$.
So let $A_t$ be point of intersection on x-axis and $B_t$ on y-axis of the before mentioned tangent $t$.

So tangent has the equation:

$y-y_0=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$

I have to find such tangent t, that the distance between $A_t  (A,0)$ and $B_t(0,B)$ will be minimal.

So the function will be: $d=A^2+B^2$

And i have to get either $A$ or $B$ as a function of the other, so that i can calculate the minimum.

So my initial idea; should i just insert  $A_t  (A,0)$ , $B_t(0,B)$ into the tangent equation, or is that the wrong approach.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $t$, the tangent at the point $(t, a^{n+1}/t^{n})$, as you correctly stated, is given by the line of equation
$$y - f(t) = f'(t)(x - t). $$

For this line we calculate easily the points f intersection with the $x$- and $y$-axis: by letting $y = 0$ we get 
$$ x(t) = (tf'(t) - f(t))/f'(t) = \frac{-na^{n+1}/t^n - a^{n+1}/t^n}{-na^{n+1}/t^{n+1}} = \frac{n+1}{n}t $$
while from $x = 0$ we get
$$ y(t) = -tf'(t) + f(t) = n\frac{a^{n+1}}{t^n} + \frac{a^{n+1}}{t^n} = (n+1)\frac{a^{n+1}}{t^n}. $$
Hence we must minimize over $t$ the function
$$ d(t) = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 = \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}t^2 + \frac{(n+1)^2a^{2n+2}}{t^{2n}}. $$
By differentiating we get
$$ 0 = d'(t_{min}) = \frac{2(n+1)^2}{n^2}t_{min} - 2n\frac{(n+1)^2a^{2n+2}}{t_{min}^{2n+1}}, $$
from where you find
$$ \frac{t_{min}^{2n+2}}{2na^{2n+2}} = \frac{n^2}{2} \implies t_{min} = \pm \sqrt[2n+2]{n^3}a. $$

Comment: When letting $x=0$ is not there $y(t) = f(t) - tf*(t) $ since $x=0$ we get $f'(t)(-t) $ on the right side.

Comment: You are right, fixed.